# Get most recent older value from one hour ago in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I want to get the most recent older value from one hour ago in my data but when I execute this query

```
SELECT locid, value
FROM  table2
WHERE date_sub(t_stamp, interval 1 hour) 
and locid = '2815'
order by t_stamp desc
```

I get all the values. How can I fix this?

The output should be

```
locid  | value
2815   | 13.0
```

Here's the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3c89/5

Comment: Are you just missing `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: [**See fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3c89/7)

Comment: The most recent is 10.  Why in your question do you say you want 30.1?

Comment: @Linger I want to get the most recent older value from 1 hour ago, which is 30.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Following query will get the current hour and subtract one from it and then compare it to the hour of `t_stamp`.

```
SELECT locid, value
FROM  table2
WHERE DATE(t_stamp) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
AND HOUR(t_stamp) = HOUR(CURRENT_TIME) -1
AND locid = '2815'
ORDER BY t_stamp desc
LIMIT 1
```

Or the following query might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT locid, value
FROM  table2
WHERE t_stamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
AND locid = '2815'
ORDER BY t_stamp desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: One more thing, I used your code to get the value from yesterday, i tried `select current date_first` then the output was `2013-11-26'` then i did `select current_date - 1` then the out was `20131125` how can i format the `20131125` to become `2013-11-25` so that the query result won't be null?

Comment: I don't know if I fully follow what you are saying.  Can you post your full SQL query?

Comment: Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3c89/40 the output of the date yesterday becomes `20131125` i tried your code on my actual database but instead of getting the value from one hour i get the value from yesterday. how can i convert that `20131125` to `2013-11-25` cos when i run this query in my database http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c92c/1 even if its showing result on the sqlfiddle its showing null on my database it was because the output of current_date - 1 is 20131125 and not as 2013-11-25.. did that make sense?

Comment: That does not make sense. When comparing dates it doesn't matter if the dashes are there or not. See [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/816eb5/5/0) example. MySQL knows how to decipher dates and compare them accordingly.  If you really need the date formatted try [***DATE_FORMAT()***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a LIMIT to your query to return only the first row.

```
SELECT locid, value
FROM  table2
WHERE date_sub(t_stamp, interval 1 hour) 
and locid = '2815'
order by t_stamp desc limit 1
```

Comment: it's still getting the latest. i want to get the most recent older value from one hour ago

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT 1 to return only the top value

Comment: i want to get the most recent older value not the latest

Comment: @user3014771 - you can combine LIMIT 1 with ORDER BY.

Comment: @andrewsi combine how?

Comment: @user3014771 - you can use them both in the same statement - `ORDER BY t_stamp DESC LIMIT 1`. But I'm confused about what you mean about 'the most recent older value'; what, exactly, are you trying to find? Do you mean the newest? Or am I missing something?